# Dictionary update using a loop to insert the same key multiple times is only inserting the last value

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I don't understand why my dictionary isn't updating. If I enter two names, e.g. `Joe` and `Josh`, then I'd like the out put to be `'name : Joe, name: Josh'`, but at the moment the result is `'name: Josh'`.

How can I do this properly?

```
names_dic = {}
print("Enter the number of friends joining (including you):")
num_people = int(input())
print("Enter the name of every friend (including you), each on a new line:")
if num_people == 0:
    print("No one is joining for the party")
else:
    for _ in range(num_people):
        names = str(input())
        another_dict = {'name': names}
        names_dic.update(another_dict)
print(names_dic)
```

Comment: A dict can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: This seems like it should just be a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: you should use list, since your usecase does not reflect any usefulness of dict. Also no need to use `.update` you can simply put `your_dict[key]=value`. Here the key is `name` in both the cases. Since dict does not contain duplicate key you are left with `name:josh` since it is the lst updated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the content of the dict, as you are using always the same key. If you want to store your frinds in a list you could use a list of dicts:

```
names_list = []
print("Enter the number of friends joining (including you):")
num_people = int(input())
print("Enter the name of every friend (including you), each on a new line:")
if num_people == 0:
    print("No one is joining for the party")
else:
    for _ in range(num_people):
        names = str(input())
        names_list.append({'name': names})
print(names_list)
```

With Joe and Josh you then get

```
[{'name': 'Joe'}, {'name': 'Josh'}]
```

Another idea would be make the names as keys

```
names_dic = {}
print("Enter the number of friends joining (including you):")
num_people = int(input())
print("Enter the name of every friend (including you), each on a new line:")
if num_people == 0:
    print("No one is joining for the party")
else:
    for _ in range(num_people):
        names = str(input())
        another_dict = {names: 'Joins the party'}
        names_dic.update(another_dict)
print(names_dic)
```

With Joe and Josh you then get

```
{'Joe': 'Joins the party', 'Josh': 'Joins the party'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me so quickly! Your answer was extremely helpful

Answer (score 0):

Key values must be unique in a dictionary, but you have multiple "name" keys.  I *think* what you want is a set, which will maintain one copy of each of the names you add to it.

Comment: Why set over a list? What if two friends have the same names?